# PHP make URLs look nicer

Tags: php, routes, url-routing

I'm currently working on a little PHP/JS application, but I'm absolutely not satisfied with the way the URL's look. They are something like `domain.com/file.php?id=2&delete=true` or something similar...

Now I'm trying to get the URL's in a nicer way, something like `domain.com/file/2`, leading to the same result. Now I found some little routing plugins, but I don't know if that's the thing I need. Basically I don't really mind about dirty code or whatever, as I'm just trying and learning, but the URL's would really matter to me.

Is there an easy DIY solution for these things or should I use a routing-plugin or what's the best way to do this?

**Edit**: it's not really a duplicate, I wasn't looking for doing all with htaccess, as this is limited, I'm looking for a PHP-Solution with minimal routing

Comment: Why not use some framework? For example codeigniter? It's lightweight framework, good for small apps.

Comment: @MarekZavoronok Cause it’s not hard to do yourself, and it helps you learn…?

Comment: @MarekZavoronok Absolutely agree to deceze, because I'm working on PHP for myself and I want to program as much as possible for myself in order to learn and get better

Comment: Re “not a duplicate”: the basic idea is to use mod_rewrite to handle URLs independently of physical files. How you “route” afterwards within PHP is up to you.

Comment: no, not at all. the basic idea is to use php scripts or php routing to handle URL's.

Comment: Yeah, the first step for that is to rewrite every request to one PHP file using mod_rewrite. If you need more specific help, ask a more specific question.